# Discord.js v12 Emoji List Command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make an emoji list command in discord.js v12. However, if I run the command in a server with many emojis I get an Invalid Form Body error as the embed description cannot have more than 2048 characters. Hence I tried to split the message. Here is my code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
 name: 'emojis',
 description: "Gets a guild's emojis",

 async run(client, message, args) {
  const charactersPerMessage = 2000;
  const emojis = message.guild.emojis.cache.map((e) => {
   return `${e} **-** \`:${e.name}:\``;
  });
  const numberOfMessages = Math.ceil(emojis.length / charactersPerMessage);
  const embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle(`Emoji List`);
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfMessages; i++) {
   message.channel.send(
    embed.setDescription(
     emojis.slice(i * charactersPerMessage, (i + 1) * charactersPerMessage)
    )
   );
  }
 },
};
```

Even after this, I get the same Invalid Body Form error. Here is the error I get:

```
(node:211) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.description: Must be 2048 or fewer in length.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/Utki-the-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:211) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:211) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can you help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact that `emojis` is an array, not a string. The [`.map`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) function returns an array (of strings in your case). The fix should be quite simple, just add a [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) at the end of the `.map` function to make it a string. Check the code below:

```js
const emojis = message.guild.emojis.cache
 .map((e) => `${e} **-** \`:${e.name}:\``)
 .join(', ');
```

Comment: Also If this is possible. So in this way the list is sent however at the end of the list a part of the list is cut off and the rest is continued in another embed. Is  it possible that the bot sends the complete emoji in first list and not cut off any of the emojis and continue to next embed

Comment: Take a look at how [Discord JS implements the split property](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/util/Util.js#L58-L79). This tries to split the message cleanly on a newline (\n). You can try splitting the message on a comma because that is the separator between emojis in your code